# `end` with an or operator

Tags: ruby

I am reading a code piece like this:

```
def majority_agreed_commit
  current_commit = log_container.last_commit

  current_term_match_indices = match_indices.values.map do |match_index|
    match_index.downto(current_commit).find do |i|
      log_container.term(i) == current_term
    end || current_commit
  end
```

I don't understand the meaning of this: `end || current_commit`. Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Block

```
match_index.downto(current_commit).find do |i|
  log_container.term(i) == current_term
end
```

returns a value, this value is logically added against `current_commit` and the result is being yielded in topmost `map`:

```
match_indices.values.map do |...|
  BLOCK_RESULT || current_commit
end
```

Comment: you mean,  every time the result will be the new "current_commit" which will be used in next iteration? What does this "||" operator mean here?

Comment: Boolean `OR` in ruby is evaluated to the first operand, unless it is `falsey` (either `nil`, or `false`.) Otherwise it yields the value of the second operand. http://ruby.about.com/od/control/a/Boolean-Operators.htm

Comment: thanks. Though, never seen this kinda syntax  in cpp,java,python or js.

Comment: Are you kidding? You’ve never seen `opt_value = get_option('opt') || 10` in javascript? BTW, welcome.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators `||` https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not

Comment: @BufBills: the result of a method call can be an operand of a boolean operator in C++, Java, Python, or JavaScript as well. For example, in JavaScript: `matchIndex.downto(currentCommit).find(i => logContainer.term(i) == currentTerm) || currentCommit`, in Python: `match_index.downto(current_commit).find(lambda i: log_container.term(i) == current_term) or current_commit`, in Java: `matchIndex.downto(currentCommit).find(i -> logContainer.term(i) == currentTerm) || currentCommit`.